# Ubuntu 14.04 freezes frequently with dual boot windows 10

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, drivers, nvidia

I have a Dell New Inspiron 7559 laptop with Intel and Nvidia GTX960M Hybrid Graphic Card. I'm facing some problems with the system after installing Ubuntu on my new laptop.

First, sometimes, the grub menu is not able to boot into Ubuntu 14.04 but stuck at the loading screen of Ubuntu logo.

Also, the other problem, and more serious one, is that it frequently freezes for no reason. Sometimes, it freezes about 3 times in half an hour. I am wondering if this has anything to do with my graphics card as I have seen some earlier posts mentioning this problem, but I haven't found any solution to solve my problem yet. So, I am really looking forward for some help here.

Below is the output as I run `sudo lshw -c video`

```
  *-display               
   description: 3D controller
   product: GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: a2
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
   resources: irq:321 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:df000000-df07ffff

  *-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 06
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:322 memory:dd000000-ddffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```